# Javascript increase value of variable in object

Tags: javascript, object

```
let myPos = 0
let load = new Riload({
    el: '#loadMyArticle',
    url: '../users/myArticle',
    data: 'myPos='+myPos,
    sukses: () => {
        myPos = myPos + 1
        console.log(myPos)
    }
})
```

I have myPos variable where the default value is 0. If load function successfully run, myPos will increased + 1 in every callback. My problem, if I run console.log(myPos) in sukses callback, it can increase. But, myPos in "data" property still valued 0. How to increase this variable on data property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: `sukses` should be `success`

Comment: `data` has to be a function to accomplish such, otherwise it will concatenate the value. Regardless it will be updated or not, it will **always** be 0, since it's **declared** as a concatenation.

Comment: Try to use `this.myPos`

Comment: @Osakr myPos is in a higher scope, so let will work just fine.

Comment: @Osakr of course it will. http://jsfiddle.net/4fczuxrw/ . I'm surprised no one is guessing that whatever is said above still won't work, since it's just a concatenation, hence it will always result in a **static** string. That's impressive.

Comment: My bad so :> haha

Comment: @briosheje i could have sworn I saw a comment that gave that answer, probably got removed meantime

Answer (score 1):

```js
let myPos = 0
let load = new Riload({
  el: '#loadMyArticle',
  url: '../users/myArticle',
  data: '',
  sukses() {
    this.incrementPos()
  },
  incrementPos() {
    myPos += 1
    this.setData()
  },
  setData() {
    this.data = `myPostTracker = ${myPos}`
  }
})
```

By accessing the `data` prop via the `setData` function you can set the property however you like. I have also added an `incrementPos` function to the Object so it can be called independently of the `success` (or sukses) lifecycle callback.

I hope this helps - Originally when you call `sukses` it was indeed incrementing the `myPos` variable but the `data` prop was not being re-set so the myPos variable that you were referencing in your string concatenation was not changing/updating.

```js
let initPos = 0

const obj = {
  myPos: initPos,
  data: '',
  success() {
    this.incrementPos()
  },
  incrementPos() {
    initPos += 1
    this.myPos = initPos
    this.setData()
  },
  setData() {
    this.data = `myPostTracker = ${this.myPos}`
  }
}


obj.success()
console.log(obj.data)

obj.incrementPos()
console.log(obj.data)

obj.incrementPos()
console.log(obj.data)

obj.incrementPos()
console.log(obj.data)
```

This approach can be done without a `myPos` property on the `obj` Object.

```js
let myPos = 0

const obj = {
  data: '',
  success() {
    this.incrementPos()
  },
  incrementPos() {
    myPos += 1
    this.setData()
  },
  setData() {
    this.data = `myPostTracker = ${myPos}`
  }
}


obj.success()
console.log(obj.data)

obj.incrementPos()
console.log(obj.data)

obj.incrementPos()
console.log(obj.data)

obj.incrementPos()
console.log(obj.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is merely an example of concept. access your newly created object during the "sukses" callback, and update the "data" field from there

```
let myPos = 0 
let load = new Riload({
    el: '#loadMyArticle',
    url: '../users/myArticle',
    data: 'myPos='+myPos,
    sukses: () => {
        myPos = myPos + 1
        load.data = 'myPos='+myPos
        console.log(myPos)
    } })
```